# How to notice when DialogFragment is dismissed in my Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-dialogfragment

I'm navigating from a `Fragment` to a `DialogFragment`. What I want to do is notice when this `DialogFragment` is dismissed in my `Fragment` to do something.

I'm trying doing this updating a `LiveData` but for some reason,when the `DialogFragment` is closed, the `LiveData` value is never true like I'm trying to do.

### MyFragment:

```
private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel() //Using Koin
btn1.setOnClickListener{
   findNavController().navigate(R.id.my_dialog_fragment)
}

myViewModel.dialogFragmentIsClosed.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){isClosed->
if(isClosed)
  //do something
}
```

### MyViewModel:

```
private val _dialogFragmentIsClosed = MutableLiveData(false)
val dialogFragmentIsClosed: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _dialogFragmentIsClosed
fun isDialogFragmentClosed(closed:Boolean){
  _dialogFragmentIsClosed.postValue(closed)
}
```

### DialogFragment:

```
private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel() //Using Koin

override fun onDismiss(dialog:DialogInterface){
  myViewModel.isDialogFragmentClosed(true)
  val bundle = bundleOf(Pair("argBoolean",true))
  findNavController().navigate(R.id.my_fragment,bundle)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your DialogFragment and MyFragment are not sharing the same instance of MyViewModel.

To achieve your goal, you should check this document:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#additional_considerations

You will open DialogFragment from MyFragment, then observer the result from DialogFragment.

If you want to share the same instance of ViewModel, change to use activityViewModel()  ( instead of using viewModel() )

Answer (score 1):

You could use a interface to listen dismiss event. This is a simple way

First, create interface and put it in your dialog fragment:

```
interface CloseListener {
    fun onClose()
}
class YourDialog(private val listener: CloseListener) : DialogFragment() {
   override fun onDismiss(dialog:DialogInterface){
      listener.onClose()
   }
}
```

And then, in your fragment, calling dialogfragment like this:

```
val yourDialog = YourDialog(object: CloseListener{
   override fun onClose() {
       //do something here, such as set value for your viewModel
   }
})
yourDialog.show(childFragmentManager, null)
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: You shouldn't pass a listener through fragment constructor. It may crash the app